# Create button image external link to other site MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

What is the simplest way to create a button image external link to other site? I've been searching for this but the answers seem to be so complicated! Thank you for your help!
I make things like this but it's showing nothing on the browser

```
<div id="pic1">

            @foreach (var item in ViewData["GiayVai"] as List<ShoeShelling.SanPham>)
            {
                <img src="@Url.Content(@item.HINHANH)" />
                @item.TENSP;<br/>
                 <b>Giá:</b>     @item.DONGIA; <b>đ</b>


                @Html.ActionLink("Chi tiết", "Details", new { id=@item.MASP })

                break;

           <a href= "@item.LINKBAOKIM"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Image/muahangBaoKim.png")" /></a>       

            }

        </div>
```

if I move `<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Image/muahangBaoKim.png")" />` outside the loop, it does show the image. But It must be in the loop to get the link. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_image

Comment: @Dilish: Don't link to w3schools. http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: If the image shows when you move it outside of the for loop, then most likely, your for loop isn't actually doing anything. Are you sure that there are members in the list contained in `ViewData["GiayVai"]`. If the list is empty, the for loop is essentially skipped over.

Comment: @Chris Pratt: the list is not empty for sure. I saw the problem, the "BREAK" -_- man I'm such a fool